# React Native: How to install 3rd Party Native Module Plugin on Post-Integration .xworkspace Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I've successfully integrated a very basic React Native Project(without any Native Module Plugin) with the existing iOS Native App(Written in Objective-C) on which presentViewController and dismissViewController are both implemented successfully.

However I cannot find any post and official documentation to show how to install those third-party react-native native modules, such as react-native-deivce-info, react-native-camera etc., into the post-integration .xworkspace project. Can anybody show me the steps? For example, the "react-native-video". Thank you so much.